# select sql data order by date

Tags: php, sql, date, sql-order-by

I have a table with a column called `date`, as a varchar.  The contents are specifically formatted like 'March 11, 2011'.

How can I select the results have them correctly ordered by date?

Comment: You also need to specify which DB you're talking about.  The answer will involve using DB-specific date parsing and casting functions, but we can't help you if you don't help us understand those details.

Comment: Fix your data model. Never ever store dates as varchars. If you store them using the datatype `date` you won't have any problems sorting it.

Comment: Could you show some example data and the table structures?

Comment: SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE date >= CURDATE() AND date <= CURDATE() - 10days

Answer (score 3):

I'm blindly assuming MySQL here, because it makes sense in the context of this question.  Nobody using another database engine would dare create this problem in the first place.

[`STR_TO_DATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) to the rescue!  Given the format "March 01, 2000", the following conversion should work.

```
SELECT STR_TO_DATE(column_name, '%M %d, %Y')
  FROM TableName
 WHERE ...
 ORDER BY STR_TO_DATE(column_name, '%M %d, %Y')
```

You may need to adjust the [format string](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) a bit.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the [DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date) function along with [CURDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate).

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE DATE(your_date_column) = CURDATE()
```

This will select all rows where `your_date_column` is todays date.

If you want to select all rows where `your_date_column` is between two dates, you can simply use [BETWEEN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between):

```
SELET * FROM tbl WHERE your_date_column BETWEEN '20111-03-20' AND '2011-03-30'
```

Comment: no, not like that i have to select the rows between two dates for example :  -

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE DATE(your_date_column) >= CURDATE() AND DATE(your_date_column) <= Some other date

Answer (score 1):

If your two dates are in variables such as `$date_begin` and `$date_end`, you could use an SQL query like the following one, to get data that's between those dates :

```
select *
from your_table
where date between '$date_begin' and '$date_end'
```

*(Not sure I quite understand the question)*

If you want to get the rows that correspond to the current date, you'll need to variables :

- `$current` ; that would be like `2011-03-20` -- which means `2011-03-20 00:00:00`
- `$next` ; that would be like `2011-03-21` -- which means `2011-03-21 00:00:00`

And you'll use a query like this one :

```
select *
from your_table
where date >= '$current' and date < '$next'
```

To select data that has its date which is greater or equal that today ; and that's before tomorrow.

In any case, try to not apply an SQL function on your date column ; don't do anything like this :

```
where some_function(date) >= ...
```

Doing this, your database engine would have to apply that function to all lines of your table, not using any index you might have on the `date` column -- and this will result in bad performances.