# How to select the data according to today's date

Tags: php, sql, date, select

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [select sql data order by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5360427/select-sql-data-order-by-date)

i have a table where a column named as date have a date format 2011-03-11. How can i select the different rows according to today's date for example today is 2011-03-20 i have to select the data b/w 2011-03-30.

One more thing both of these dates are variable !! such as today's date and date after 10 days or date before 10 days.

Does Sql have such a type of query which i can simply use ?? or any other solution for this ??